# Dynamically display table based on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello my fellow programmers, I am a ruby on rails noob and need some help:

Based on today's date I am querying the db and getting the results as an array.

```
    @cr = [#<CRate id: 1, currency: "AUD", rate: 2.0, datetime: "2013-10-09 22:59:59">,
 #<CRate id: 7, currency: "USD", rate: 10.0, datetime: "2013-10-09 29:50:50">,
 #<CRate id: 9, currency: "EUR", rate: 20.0, datetime: "2013-10-09 22:59:59">,
 #<CRate id: 12, currency: "RUB", rate: 12.0, datetime: "2013-10-09 22:59:59">,
 #<CRate id: 14, currency: "AUD", rate: 18.0, datetime: "2013-10-09 29:50:50">]
```

**Question:** I need to dynamically display the table based on currency(header), depending on the time, if rate exist then I display it else output is nil. Like this table below:

[image]

I have tried to do this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Time</th>
        <% @currency = @cr.collect(&:currency) %>
        <% @currency.each do |cur| %>
            <th><%= cur %></th>
        <% end %>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
            <td><%= @datetime = @cr.collect(&:datetime) %></td>
            <% @rate = @cr.collect(&:rate) %>
            <% @rate.each do |r| %>
                <td><%= r %></td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This doesn't work because the thead is updated with 2 AUD's and I don't know how to proceed. Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you will have to group the results by date. for that to work, you could create a hash, use the dates as a key and then put an array of all the rates as a value.

Comment: @phoet: @cr.group_by{|a| a.datetime = "2013-10-09 22:59:59"} like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need unique currency types, so line no. 4 will be:

```
<% @currency = @cr.collect(&:currency).uniq %>
```

Secondly, you need to get rates based on datetime and currency type (since you have not specified Rails version, I will try and write a working solution which might not be best solution):

```
<tbody>
  <% @datetime = @cr.collect(&:datetime).uniq %>
  <% @datetime.each do |dt| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
      <td><%= dt %></td>
      <% @currency.each do |curr| %>
        <td><%= @cr.select {|o| o.currency == curr && o.datetime == dt}.rate %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

HTH

Edit: This seems to be an inefficient way to solve this problem because you are relying too much on arrays in a way that they will always come in order you are expecting. I would like rather create a Hash (better known as key-value pair) of `@cr` like `{'first_datetime' => {'AUD' => '10', 'RUB' => '20'}, 'second_datetime' => {'AUD' => '50', 'RUB' => ''}}` and so forth.

Edit 2: In your controller, create a hash and 2 sets like:

```
@currencies = Set.new
@datetimes = Set.new
@currency_rate_datewise = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = {}}
@cr.each do |cr|
  @currencies.add cr.currency
  @datetimes.add cr.datetime
  @currency_rate_datewise[cr.datetime][cr.currency] = cr.rate
end
```

Now your view could be simplified to:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Time</th>
        <% @currencies.each do |cur| %>
            <th><%= cur %></th>
        <% end %>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @datetimes.each do |datetime| %>
            <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
                <td><%= datetime %></td>
                <% @currencies.each do |currency| %>
                    <td><%= @currency_rate_datewise[datetime][currency] || 'nil' %></td>
                <% end %>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Although, I would have used `group_by` selectively, but I guess, it is better if you stick with learning such things at beginner's stage. I have written this from top of my head, please post a comment if something's wrong.

HTH

Comment: How to generate a hash like that for my case? I am lost here sorry.

Comment: Updated my answer for details.

Comment: Great :-) There is a minor typo in the controller code, it should be
each **do** |cr| instead of each |cr|.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `group_by` rails helper for that. see the documentation:

> group_by() Collect an enumerable into sets, grouped by the result of a
>   block. Useful, for example, for grouping records by date.

Example:

```
latest_transcripts.group_by(&:day).each do |day, transcripts|
  p "#{day} -> #{transcripts.map(&:class).join(', ')}"
end
"2006-03-01 -> Transcript"
"2006-02-28 -> Transcript"
"2006-02-27 -> Transcript, Transcript"
"2006-02-26 -> Transcript, Transcript"
"2006-02-25 -> Transcript"
"2006-02-24 -> Transcript, Transcript"
"2006-02-23 -> Transcript"
```